# Using fminsearch error

Tags: math, matlab

I have function:

```
function f=kriteriyLR3(a,w,ft)
ye=[0.5 1 2 3.5 4 3.8 2.9 2.5 1 0.3];
t=[0.2 0.3 0.35 1.6 1.78 1.8 2 2.3 2.5 3];
s=0;
for i=1:10
  s=s+(ye(i)-a*sin(w*t(i)+ft))^2;
end
f=s;
```

I want to minimize it and I do the following:

```
a=1;
w=1;
ft=1;
x = fminsearch('kriteriyLR3',[], a,w,ft);
```

I receive the folloing errors:

```
>> mainLR3
Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

Error in fminsearch (line 191)
fv(:,1) = funfcn(x,varargin{:});

Error in mainLR3 (line 12)
x = fminsearch('kriteriyLR3',[], a,w,ft);
```

As far as I understand the dimensions mismatch, but I have no idea how to fix it. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read the help for [`fminsearch`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/fminsearch.html)?

Your calling syntax is all wrong. I think what you want is:

```
x = fminsearch(@(x) kriteriyLR3(x(1),x(2),x(3)), [a,w,ft],[]);
```

If you look at the syntax you're using, you'll see that you're trying to start from `[]`, which means that `funfcn(x,varargin{:})` will return `[]`, which doesn't match the expected size.

Answer (score 2):

`fminsearch` will optimize over one variable, but this variable can be a vector.  Here is a relevant example from the help:

```
     f = @(x,c) x(1).^2+c.*x(2).^2;  % The parameterized function.
     c = 1.5;                        % The parameter.
     X = fminsearch(@(x) f(x,c),[0.3;1])
```

`fminsearch` will find the minimum over `x`, while keeping `c` constant at `1.5`, and starting at `[0.3;1]`.  You have to decide whether `a`, `w`, or `ft` are what you are minimizing over, as @woodchips mentioned.  Using anonymous functions with `fminsearch` is really valuable - make sure you understand the simple examples and how anonymous functions work.  Start with things that work, and slowly modify them with your own examples so that you can understand the incremental changes.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You are minimizing this function as a function of what parameter? What variable should fminsearch vary? What are the starting values? Read the help for fminsearch. What is the second input argument? Why are you passing in empty brackets there?

What is the third argument? READ THE HELP. You cannot simply pass in arguments in arbitrary or even random order, and expect fminsearch to divine what you intend.

Comment: I try to minimize function as a function of 3 parameters: a, w, ft. THe second input parameter stands for options.